# What could make these two queries returning different results?

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I have an ELB logs table on Amazon Athena, and I'm trying to request daily requests by url. The table is structure is [the one described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/elasticloadbalancer-classic-logs.html), but I'm also added partitions for day, month and year for querying logs by day, month, etc...
I'm partitioning my table with a query like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE elb_logs ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (year='2019',month='03',day='*') location 's3://my-logs-bucket/my-load-balancer/AWSLogs/526654419886/elasticloadbalancing/eu-west-1/2019/03/'
```

Then I ask for the log entries on the first of March 2019 like this:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
    FROM elb_logs
    WHERE year='2019'
    AND month='03'
    AND day='01'
```

and get 590 results, then if I execute this query:

```sql
SELECT count(*), DATE(from_iso8601_timestamp(time))
    FROM elb_logs
    WHERE year='2019'
         AND month='03'
         AND day='*'
    GROUP BY DATE(from_iso8601_timestamp(time))
```

I get 590 as the count as well for the first of March, BUT if I execute this one (without the day condition):

```sql
SELECT count(*), DATE(from_iso8601_timestamp(time))
    FROM elb_logs
    WHERE year='2019'
         AND month='03'
    GROUP BY DATE(from_iso8601_timestamp(time))
```

I get 1180 as a resulting count, which is incorrect. Why is this? What's the difference from specifying `DAY='*'` and not specifying DAY? Shouldn't they be equivalent?

Comment: What were you wanting to achieve with `day='*'` in the `PARTITION` statement?

Comment: I partitioned the table like that in order to be able to query logs for any of the days if needed. I actually can't find the documentation where I read that because I made it quite a long time ago.

Comment: That is effectively setting the `day` field to be `*` for any rows contained within that partition. The field contents is set from the name of the partition directory. In fact, I'm not sure where you would be getting rows for `day='01'` unless you have a separate partition created with that specific value.

Comment: Well, that clarifies thing a little bit for me, the day='01' results may come from another partition executed specifically trying to do something else. Can these values be set more than once, I mean, if I set * for a S3 folder and then set another partition using other char. Could this be queried by both or the first one gets overwritten?

Comment: The default method for partitioning is that the directory name defines the value, eg `s3://my-bucket/table/year=2019/month=03/day=01`. In this case, all rows within that directory will have those values for the named fields. Alternatively, when using `ADD PARTITION` using the syntax you provided, it is saying that all rows within that nominated directory have `year='2019',month='03',day='*'`.

Comment: Thanks! This gives me a better understanging on how partitions work! I can tackle my problem now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are partition names and partition locations.

Partitions:

- `month=03,day=01`
- `month=03,day=*`

When you query without condition on the `day` column, both partitions match.
As it happens, they contains same files (since they share their physical location).
As there is (apparently) no deduplication of the files being read (the partitions are supposed to be non-overlapping), the same data files are being read twice.